# How to combine two for loops python

Tags: python

So I have these two for loops

```
for pokemon in pokemonList:
    for key in pokemon:
        print(key)
        break

for files in os.walk("./sprites/"):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
```

I am trying to use the values from the first pokemonList.pokemon to rename the files in the sprites folder.

In Javascript id do something like

```
for(i=0;i<pokemonList.length;i++){loop through both using i here}
```

But I am unsure of how to do this in python. Thank you in advance.

pokemonList:

```
[{'Milcery'}, {'Alcremie'}, {'Alcremie'}, {'Alcremie'}, {'Alcremie'}, {'Alcremie'}, {'Alcremie'}, {'Alcremie'}, {'Alcremie'}, {'Alcremie'}, {'Falinks'}, {'Pincurchin'}, {'Snom'}, {'Frosmoth'}, {'Stonjourner'}, {'Eiscue'}, {'Eiscue'}, {'Indeedee'}, {'Indeedee'}, {'Morpeko'}, {'Morpeko'}, {'Cufant'}, {'Copperajah'}, {'Dracozolt'}, {'Arctozolt'}, {'Dracovish'}, {'Arctovish'}, {'Duraludon'}, {'Dreepy'}, {'Drakloak'}, {'Dragapult'}, {'Zacian'}, {'Zacian'}, {'Zamazenta'}, {'Zamazenta'}, {'Eternatus'}, {'Eternatus'}]
```

Comment: What does `pokemonList` look like? Please show a [mcve] along with actual/expected output. Thanks. That said, I'm guessing you want `zip` to iterate the two lists simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexes too:

```
for i in range(len(pokemonList)):
    # do whatever you want with the i index
```

Answer (score 0):

can do the same sort of thing in python by indexing the list with square brackets and using the len function to get the length of the list:

```
     for i in range (0, len(pokemonList)):
         print(pokemonList[i])
```

List indexes start at 0 in python.

Answer (score 0):

If the range for "pokemon" and "files" is same you can setup the loop as

```py
for pokemon,files in zip(pokemonList, os.walk("./sprites/")):
    print(pokemon, files)
    # do other stuff
```